# True SEO urls in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

I'm building a simple cms system and would like to have true seo urls with hierarchical levels of pages like http://www.mydomain.com/lorem-ipsum/dolar/sit-amet/. Whats the best approach to successfully implement urls like this?

Comment: Nice question! What did you get so far?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) is a good one on routing, though for MVC 1.0, it still holds for MVC 2.0.

By default MVC provides support for hierarchical levels of pages in a SEO manner. If structured properly, your URLs will be SEO friendly.

Thanks

Comment: I don't want any "hardcoded" url paths in my cms, lets say i want to rename my search page from search to mysearchpage this approach does not seem to hold up? It would be interesting to see if someone successfully has build a cms where the editor can rename and create pages exactly as they want the structure to be. In my test application I have a catchall route like this {*pagePath} but that may not be the best solution?

Comment: just change the action name when you want to change the the page name, Or you can use rewrite module of iis to redirect or rewrite the URLs to the old ones with out changing any of your code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at these http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/34/asp-net-mvc-and-clean-seo-friendly-urls ?

Comment: Mayhe I solved it by creating a custom route that works with hierarchical urls without the controller name in the url. You can follow my project on github https://github.com/kloojed/BrickPile